# Is it possible to do flashback after truncate?

Tags: oracle

Is there any possibility of doing flashback after truncate ? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly no. At least not by default and not directly. For this you need to read about [Flashback Data Archives](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10471/adfns_flashback.htm#ADFNS01011) . By default they are disabled for all tables, but it can be activated, and will preserve your data even after a truncate. Moreover, even if you have the FDAs, you cannot just flashback the table, because TRUNCATE is a DDL operation, and will throw you an error that the table definition has been changed.

What you can do though, is to select the data to a point from the flashback table, and insert it back in yours:

```
insert into table1
select * from table1 as of timestamp to_timestamp(<your_time>)
```

Note! This can be done only after you have flashback data archives for that table.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

No, You can't flashback a truncated table. But you can use  traditional backup/recovery or FLASHBACK database to restore the table's data.
Try to flashback database to a earlier timestamp or System change number and export and import the truncated table.

Check this [link](https://gavinsoorma.com/2009/08/using-flashback-to-rollback-a-truncate/) for more details.

Comment: Please add the details from the link to your answer. As it stands, your answer will lose a lot of its value if/when the link's target is moved/deleted.